# HLLC Riemann solver with shock test 2 - extension to low densities

Tags: reference-request

I am currently using the HLLC solver to solve a 1-D system of Euler equations with very satisfactory results.

However, there are cases where my solution produces low-density, high velocity states, which lead to strange heating at the origin. The heating is strange, as I am running with a $\gamma_{adiabatic}$ close to 1, hence the simulation is quais-isothermal.
I've double and triple-checked my boundary conditions, and am fairly certain its not that. My other idea is that this situation is resembling the anomalous shock tube test-2 heating, as seen in HLLC solvers in general (circled in red in the image below).

[image]

**Hence my question:**
As the HLLC solver is otherwise a nearly perfect solver, I was curious whether there is a fix for this near-vacuum overheating. I am mainly asking for a reference.

Toro's references in the HLLC chapter turned out interesting papers, but not a fix for this specific issue. I am also aware of the keyword 'drying and wetting' for near-vacuum problems with the shallow water equations, but searching for this in conjunction with the Euler system and fixing the overheating amounted to nothing. Therefore I am turning to the community.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to [this](http://www.prague-sum.com/download/2012/Toro_2-HLLC-RiemannSolver.pdf).see slide ~39?

Comment: @Bort No, slide 41. Test 2. As I said. Why the downvote?